# Passing another attribute to params other than the id

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I want to access the `username` attribute of my `User` model from `params` using `params[:username]`.

On my `user` model, I have

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_secure_password

  validates :email, presence: true, uniqueness: { case_sensitive: false }
  validates :username, presence: true, uniqueness: { case_sensitive: false }
  validates :password, length: { minimum: 6 }, on: :create

  def to_params
    username
  end
end
```

While on my `config/routes.rb`, I have:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  root "pages#home"

  resources :users, path: "/", except: :index
end
```

and this does partly what I want.

The routes produced are as follows:

```
     Prefix Verb   URI Pattern         Controller#Action
       root GET    /                   pages#home
      users POST   /                   users#create
   new_user GET    /new(.:format)      users#new
  edit_user GET    /:id/edit(.:format) users#edit
       user GET    /:id(.:format)      users#show
            PATCH  /:id(.:format)      users#update
            PUT    /:id(.:format)      users#update
            DELETE /:id(.:format)      users#destroy
```

where the `:id` part outputs the `username` of `User` and so I get a route like `/jim` when accessing the user's homepage.

What bugs me out is I have to use `params[:id]` when accessing the `username` on my controllers. Moreover, when I nest the resources like this:

```
  resources :users do
    resources :posts
  end
```

I get a route like `/users/:user_id/posts(.:format)` where `:user_id` is the `username`.

Is there a way I could set this up so my routes would look something like:

```
     Prefix Verb   URI Pattern                Controller#Action
       root GET    /                          pages#home
      users POST   /                          users#create
   new_user GET    /new(.:format)             users#new
  edit_user GET    /:username/edit(.:format)  users#edit
       user GET    /:username(.:format)       users#show
            PATCH  /:username(.:format)       users#update
            PUT    /:username(.:format)       users#update
            DELETE /:username(.:format)       users#destroy
```

and when I want to access the `username` from `params`, I can write `params[:username]`?

Thanks!

Comment: You're making a bad assumption that `params[:id]` actually has to correspond to the id column in your database table and that you need to change anything. The only thing that links the two is Rails convention.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For more details check rails guides [overriding-named-route-parameters](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#overriding-named-route-parameters)

Add route like this

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  root "pages#home"

  resources :users, path: "/", except: :index, param: :username do
     resources :posts
  end
end
```